# How to use laravel relations when there is DB::select()?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, relational-database

Here is my code:

```
$guarantee_tickets =  DB::select("(select ga.id, '' as unique_product_id, ga.user_id, ga.submit_time, '' as title, ga.description, '' as  tracking_code, '' as closed, '' as close_date, ga.isAdminNote from guarantee_tickets_answers ga where guarantee_tickets_id = $request->id order by ga.id desc)
                                   union all
                                  (select gt.id, gt.unique_product_id, gt.user_id, gt.submit_time, gt.title, gt.description, gt.tracking_code, gt.closed, gt.close_date, '' from guarantee_tickets gt where id = $request->id)");
```

And this:

```
dd($guarantee_tickets->user->name);
```

throws:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$user

How can I fix it?

---

Noted that I have this in both `guarantee_tickets` and `guarantee_tickets_answers` models:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: DB::Select is not using Eloquent, it's doing a raw query.

Comment: You can't have an eloquent collection with two different models. If you want only one model, you can use `Model::hydrateRaw()` instead of `DB::select()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query using `DB::Select` you are executing a raw SQL query against the database. You will receive an instance of `stdClass` that has the attributes from the database. You can read more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries).

If you want to be able to access those relations then you need to perform an Eloquent query to load the data.